# How to stop Hangfire Job without Delete the job in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, hangfire, hangfire-mongodb

I am using `Hangfire` in my .Net Core application to perform background processing. There are some scenario where I need to Quit or Stop the job execution. For that I have searched and found that I can use  `BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId);` OR `RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(jobId);` to Stop the Job, It works fine **But**, at the same It also marked job as **deleted**  so the issue is when the application pool starts again at that time that Job will not execute.

So is there any way to quit the job without delete it?

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Thanks,

Comment: This will hep you => https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/pause-disable-recurring-job/125/5

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the cron expression as never.

According to Hangfire documentation

```
     //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns cron expression that never fires. Specifically 31st of February
    public static string Never()
    {
        return Yearly(2, 31);
    }
```

Example:

```
using Hangfire;

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IScheduledJobService>("some-id", x => x.SomeMethodToInvokeAJob(), Cron.Never());
```

Note: The IScheduledJobService is a customized service for managing the actual logic of the jobs.